# MySQL selection LIMIT by the SUM of the column

Tags: mysql, sql

help with the SQL query.

table:

> id | rate
>
> 1 | 15
>
> 2 | 15
>
> 3 | 10
>
> 4 | 20
>
> 5 | 25
>
> 6 | 20
>
> 7 | 15

I need to make a selection under the criterion - the sum of SUM (rate) 32

I need a conclusion:

> id | rate
>
> 1 | 15
>
> 2 | 15
>
> 3 | 10

ie as in the amount of accumulated 32 on recording output is not necessary.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: not sure if I understood could u please add some data on http://sqlfiddle.com and the expected outcome.

Comment: I suggest you look at this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/839704/sum-until-certain-point-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Please note that what you call `id` is not really an id in this context. It is a rownumber. Id's are not for ordering, they are for uniquely identifying rows. That's why I changed id to nr in this example.

In this solution I assume that nr is unique for this table. Unfortunately, the function ROW_NUMBER() to generate rownumbers is not available in MySQL.

First we have a query that calculates the incremental sum for each row_nr:

```
SELECT SUM(rate) FROM T WHERE nr <= t1.nr
```

Then we find the lowest rownumber, for which the incremental sum is higher than or equal to 32:

```
SELECT MIN(nr) FROM
(SELECT nr FROM T t1
WHERE (SELECT SUM(rate) FROM T WHERE nr <= t1.nr) >= 32
) t2
```

Finally, we select all rows with a rownumber smaller than or equal to this number.

```
SELECT * FROM T
WHERE nr <=
(SELECT MIN(nr) FROM
(SELECT nr FROM T t1
WHERE (SELECT SUM(rate) FROM T WHERE nr <= t1.nr) >= 32
) t2);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b60a/14

Comment: My version does not work http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9eba0c/2 need CURRENT_VALUE sum = 2. But the query produces recordings with the ummah CURRENT_VALUE 4. And tell me how to sort by PRICE from highest to lowest.

Comment: It doesn't work because in this solution I assumed that `nr` could be treated as a row_number. In your fiddle you try to apply it to price, which fails because this is a row_number. Therefore it also not clear if two rows have equal price, which should be included first.