# MySql: get all matching rows up to a total sum of a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an orders table (which are basically offers to sell an item at a given price)

```
id | price | qty
-----------------
1    0.11    12
2    0.111   77
3    0.1111  51
4    0.112   62
5    0.114   17
```

Now lets say that a buy order arrives where the buyer offers to buy up 100 items for a price up to 0.112.

I want to write a query which retrieves all matching sell offers where price <= 0.112 up to 100 items. So in the example above I want to return rows 1, 2 and 3.

How can I do this in a single select statement?

Comment: That sounds like a simple where price <= 0.112 and qty <= 100. What have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/839704/sum-until-certain-point-mysql

Comment: The above example should only return the first two records unless I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to calculate a running total of the quantity by order of `id` and then restrict to those records with a running total less than 100.

```
SELECT o.id, o.price, o.qty
FROM orders o
WHERE o.price <= 0.112 AND
    (SELECT SUM(qty)
     FROM orders WHERE o.id >= id AND price <= 0.112) <= 100
```

You can test this query in the following demo:

## SQLFiddle

Comment: Sorry, that's wrong. The LIMIT clause as shown by you returns the first 100 rows, I want the rows where the sum of qty <= 100

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you do a cumulative sum using variables, and then use this information:

```
select o.*
from (select o.*, (@q := @q + qty) as runq
      from orders o cross join
           (select @q := 0) params
      order by qty
     ) t
where o.price <= 0.112 and
      o.qty - qty < 100 and
      o.qty >= 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats look simple

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE price <= 0.112 AND qty <= 100
```