# Sum and mark only closest value to controll value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, loops, sum, cumulative-sum

*(I hope the title makes sense.)*

So I have a MySQL table with kids id, date, allowance and monthly max allowance. Of course this is just an exmple but represents my problem.

| kids_id | date | allowance | money_transfer_date | monthly_max_allowance | to_keep |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 201910 | 100 | 20191001 | 500 | 0 |
| 1 | 201910 | 350 | 20191002 | 500 | 1 |
| 1 | 201910 | 140 | 20191003 | 500 | 1 |
| 2 | 201811 | 400 | 20181105 | 400 | 1 |
| 2 | 201811 | 0 | 20181106 | 400 | 0 |
| 2 | 202009 | 400 | 20200907 | 600 | 0 |
| 2 | 202009 | 100 | 20200908 | 600 | 1 |
| 2 | 202009 | 500 | 20200909 | 600 | 1 |

What I would like to achieve, is to mark all the rows in the to_keep column, based on the sum of allowance and monthly max allowance. Let me explain myself:

kids_id 1, line 2 and 3 should be kept since 140+350 is closer to 500 than 100+350.

kids_id 2, the first number is the correct, its maxed out.

kids_id 3, line 2 and 3 is the winner again, since its the closest to 600.

Of course this is just small example data, my table is miles long with lot of id-s, dates and such. So I guess whatever is the best solution, it has to loop trough my entire table. I'm afraid a simple update won't be enough.

A tried to do my homework and read a lot of stackoverflow threads, however I wasnt able to find the solution for my problem. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839704/sum-until-certain-point-mysql) - I guess - was pretty close, however monthly_max_allowance value isn't always the same.

**Edit**: update my question added the money_transfer_date column.

Comment: What logic will be applied in case several rows have same allowance? For example kid 1 have 3 rows with allowance 120, 350, 120 ?

Comment: Good question, I just updated my post, I hope I didnt break any rules. Well if the amount of allowance is the same, the money_transfer_date helps a bit, the lowest (first) date should be kept.